# Android facebook sdk with rails gem doorkeeper or devise

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, doorkeeper

I have a more structural question about designing a connection between an app (android) and a server (rails-api gem) using json. It should use facebook as authentication and afterwards handles the connection flow via a token.

My planned solution looks like this:

1. I'm planning to use the facebook sdk (client side), to get a facebook access token. 

   *a) Should I use client side? I am considering it, because the request would not be done by my server. But is the access token trustworthy?*
2. Afterwards I send the access token to my server and check it with the facebook graph api
3. If the token is correct, I create a new user with the information from the facebook graph api
4. Next I use doorkeeper for creating a oauth provider. The client gets an oauth2 access token which he uses to communicate with the server…

   *a) Should I use another authentication gem? Or should I use the facebook access token as normal authentication token?

   b)  I am not sure if I should use doorkeeper or devise. Is doorkeeper enough? I read somewhere that u should use doorkeeper for apis and devise for normal websites.

   c)  I don’t get the implicit grant stuff from oauth2. Should I consider it here?*

Thanks for our help :)

Comment: you can exchange the facebook token with your server token with the assertion grant, [doorkeeper supports it too](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-grants_assertion) with an example using facebook

Comment: what was your final approach ?